# Create Dropdown from button on menu

Tags: android, user-interface, menu

In android, I want to create a dropdown menu like the following:
[image]

I've seen some examples where there are just buttons, and no text (like QuickActionView), but none like this. If someone could direct me to some open source code, that'd be great, or point me in the correct direction.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Use SherlockActionBar library.

Answer (score 1):

Android's [ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html) does exactly this. Unfortunately, it is only available for 3.0 and up. However, you could use [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/).